# terraform "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How to add a subnet based on availability zone.
In my current setup I have 2 AZs and each AZs has 1 Private and 1 public subnets.

So, In my TF resources, I'm getting the Subnets based on filter tag as below:

```
data "aws_subnets" "private" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["Subnet-Private"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.private.ids)
  id       = each.value
}
```

Now in one of module, I would like to add one Private subnet id based on variable passed to the module as one AZ.

```
module "glue" {
subnet_id         = [for s in data.aws_subnet.private : s.id if data.aws_subnet.private.availability_zone == var.availability_zone]
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
}
```

This throws me error, how can I fix this.
var.availability_zone is a string.

```
Error: Missing resource instance key
Because data.aws_subnet.private has "for_each" set, its attributes must be
│ accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     data.aws_subnet.private[each.key]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to trying to access the attributes of `data.aws_subnet.private` without specifying the particular instance of the subnet. Since `data.aws_subnet.private` is using `for_each`, you need to iterate over each instance to access its attributes.

Try to modify the `subnet_id` assignment in the `glue` module to fix this issue:

```
module "glue" {
  subnet_id = [
    for subnet_id, subnet in data.aws_subnet.private : 
    subnet_id if subnet.availability_zone == var.availability_zone
  ]
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
}
```

Little tweak because above solution threw me `"Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required"` as the subnet_id is a string type while the return type from `for` is an array, so to get it as a string, I made below change, and it worked fine.

```
module "glue" {
  subnet_id = join(",",[
    for subnet_id, subnet in data.aws_subnet.private : 
    subnet_id if subnet.availability_zone == var.availability_zone
  ])
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now it throwing var.subnet_id is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.

Comment: thanks again, as I mentioned above the output was array while subnet_id was string input, so I made a tiny change `join(","[ for subnet_id ....] ")` and it worked fine.